# Ember. Communication between components. Breadcrumbs

Tags: ember.js, breadcrumbs, ember-components

I've implemented a custom function in a component that takes the information from the URL and returns an array, with the right name and link in order to behave as a breadcrumb.
The problem is that the last step in the process, the app has to do a transitionTo a different route/model in a completely different URL.

How can I display the breadcrumb in the final template(in the different route)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using EmberSimpleAuth, just store it in the session:

```
App.BreadcrumbController = Ember.Controller.extend({

  session: Ember.inject.service(),

  //...

  this.get('session').set('data.breadcrumbs', breadcrumbs)      

});

App.anotherController = Ember.Controller.extend({

   session: Ember.inject.service(),
   breadcrumbs: Ember.computed.alias(this.get('session.data.breadcrumbs')),

});
```

If not, you can store the array of breadcrumbs in the application controller.  You can then use it wherever you want.

```
App.BreadcrumbController = Ember.Controller.extend({

  //inject application controller so you can set a property on it
  application: Ember.inject.controller(),

  //...

  //then once you have the breadcrumbs, store them in the application controller
  application.set('breadcrumbs', breadcrumbs)      

});

App.anotherController = Ember.Controller.extend({

    //inject application controller and get the breadcrumb property
    application: Ember.inject.controller(),
    breadcrumbs: Ember.computed.alias(application.get('breadcrumbs')),

});
```